# EmberJS nesting

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Given the following code, I thought the person.index and nested person.finish routes would use the PersonController content/model property since theirs was empty/undefined? What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/MMfSf/5/

To be more concise: When you click on the id, the `{{id}}` and `{{name}}` are blank? How do I fix that?

**Functionality**

```
// Create Ember App
App = Ember.Application.create();

// Create Ember Data Store
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

// Create parent model with hasMany relationship
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
    belts: DS.hasMany( 'App.Belt' )

});

// Create child model with belongsTo relationship
App.Belt = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr( 'string' ),
    parent: DS.belongsTo( 'App.Person' )
});

// Add Person fixtures
App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Trevor",
    "belts" : [1, 2, 3]
}];

// Add Belt fixtures
App.Belt.FIXTURES = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "leather"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "type" : "rock"
}, {
    "id" : 3,
    "type" : "party-time"
}];


App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource( 'person', { path: '/:person_id' }, function() {
        this.route( 'finish' );
    });
});

// Set route behaviour
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('people');
  }
});
```

**Templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Application</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="people">
    <h2>People</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
        <li>
            <div class="debug">
                Is the person record dirty: {{this.isDirty}}
            </div>
         </li>
        <li>Id: {{#linkTo person this}}{{id}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
        <li>Belt types:
            <ul>
            {{#each belts}}
                <li>{{type}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="person">
    <h2>Person</h2>
    Id from within person template: {{id}}<br><br>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="person/index">
    Id: {{id}}<br>
    Name: <a href="#" {{action  "changeName"}}>{{name}}</a><br><br>

    {{#linkTo index}}Go back{{/linkTo}}<br>
    {{#linkTo person.finish}}Go to finish{{/linkTo}}
</script>



<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="person/finish">
    <h2>Finish</h2>
    {{id}}
</script>
```

Comment: @ken I guess it wasn't very clear, but as you can see when you click on the ID, none of the template vars in person/index are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your router:

```
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor("person");
  }
```

Instead of your's:

```
controller.set('content', this.controllerFor('person'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your views were served through different controllers, either Ember's generated one or the one you defined `PersonIndexController` and that contributed to the issue you were facing. Instead of patching your original example to make it work, i instead reworked it to show you how you should structure your views/routes to leverage Emberjs capabilities.

You should design your application/example as a series of states working and communicating with each other and captured in a Router map. In your example, you should have a `people`, `person` resource and a `finish` route with corresponding views and controllers, either you explicitly create them or let Ember do that for you, providing you're following its convention.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/MMfSf/7/) a working exemple and below I highlighted some of the most important parts of the example

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">
    <h2>People</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each  person in controller}}
        <li>
            <div class="debug">
                Is the person record dirty: {{this.isDirty}}
            </div>
         </li>
        <li>Id: {{#linkTo 'person' person}}{{person.id}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>Name: {{person.name}}</li>
        <li>Belt types:
            <ul>
            {{#each person.belts}}
                <li>{{type}}</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    <h2>Person</h2>
    Id from within person template: {{id}}<br><br>
    Id: {{id}}<br>
    Name: <a href="#" {{action  "changeName"}}>{{name}}</a><br><br>

    {{#linkTo index}}Go back{{/linkTo}}<br>
    {{#linkTo person.finish}}Go to finish{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Models, Views, Controllers and Route definitions

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", { person: "people" });

App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('people',function() {
        this.resource('person', { path: ':person_id' }, function() {
            this.route( 'finish');
        });    
    })

});

App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Person.find();
    }
})

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('people');
    }
});
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        debugger;
        return App.Person.find(params.client_id);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('person',{
            into:'application'
        })
    }
})

App.PersonFinishRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('finish',{
            into:'application'
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Whilst I appreciate your solution, it doesn't allow for template nesting into ever-deeper {{outlet}}s. I managed to solve it myself by manually setting the PersonIndexController content to the PersonController content attribute: `controller.set('content', this.controllerFor('person'));`. http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/MMfSf/9/

Comment: Has anyone tried having multiple levels of nesting through mappings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896049/ember-data-multi-level-hierarchy-with-embedded-always  I am unable to, please help.